# bb animation module not working properly after updating media and file entity modules

Tags: php, drupal

The bb animation module is not working properly after updating media and file entity modules. It is not showing the background parallax image. Could anyone please help me on this?

[image: Block edit image]

Comment: can you show some code snippet ?

Comment: I dug through the code and printed the variable array.For all images, it is returning as Array ( [fid] => 313 ) but for the block, the image file id is coming as a string (eg: 313)                                                                                                                       I am using Drupal 7.6 and Php version 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied a patch for this module. This got disturbed due to the media module update.

At line no 300 in bb_animation.module.I changed the code

from

```html
$file = file_load($background_image['fid']);
```

To

```html
    $background_image_data_type = gettype($background_image);
    switch ($background_image_data_type) {
      case 'array':
       $file = file_load($background_image['fid']);
       break;
      case 'string':
       $file = file_load($background_image);
       break;
     }
```